# Why JQuery make textarea readonly?

Tags: html, jquery, textarea

When I change dynamically the content of the textarea, the textarea for no reason becomes read-only.

```
<textarea id="note" class="form-control" style="width:100%" onKeyUp="stripDP(this);">
</textarea>

modal.find('#note').val("");
```

Comment: Does the `stripDP()` function make the textarea readonly?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this is the code `function stripDP(element){
    var x = element.value;
    var y = x.replace(/:/g, "");
    var note = y.replace(/#/g, "");
    element.value = note;
}`

Comment: The problem occurred when I showed a div (which contained my textarea) over a bootstrap modal, i resolve it make "hide" the modal. I think it's a bug due to the z-indexe. The result is not satisfactory, but it works. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred when I showed a div (which contained my textarea) over a bootstrap modal, i resolve it make "hide" the modal. I think it's a bug due to the z-index. The result is not satisfactory, but it works. Thanks to all